# Having to relogin when visiting a second Codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

I have two PHP projects with CI, and I open of both in the same browser.
*Lets assume project 1 is **A** and project 2 is **B**

What I do :

1. Open and Login on A
2. Open and view data(just listing data here, no login)

I use and active in B, I don't know the problem, but when I move to A, I need to login again.
What can I do? and what is the problem?

Help. Thanks before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change sess_cookie_name in the CI config file. Otherwise when running two application on same domain your session is getting overwritten by the other.

Please open the file application/config/config.php and look for the key sess_cookie_name and change the value from default to something else for one project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use CI, but usually setting the two projects on different subdomains will help this problem.  Cookies are set by domain/subdomain, so having two different subdomains will separate the cookies in your browser.

Comment: But this project on local only

Comment: Edit your hosts file and add project1 to 127.0.0.1 and project2 to 127.0.0.1 and access them via project1/project2 rather than localhost.